# Is this potentiometer linear or logarithmic?

Tags: potentiometer

I have old potentiometer Alps 902B-250KBX2 in my amplifier.

I need to replace it, but I don't know is linear or logarithmic?

It should be linear, because it has letter B in mark. But one my friend said that though it has letter B in mark, that it is not necessary that old pot is linear? Do you have information on how Alps labeled their pots in past?

Comment: what does the potentiometer do?

Comment: It could be a custom part for your amplifier. What amplifier it is and do you have the service manual for it?

Comment: Measure it with a multimeter?

Answer (score 7):

The confusion is because some manufacturers use A for 'log' and B for 'linear', while others use A for 'linear' and B (or C or L) for 'log'.

You can easily tell the 'taper' type with an ohmmeter. Just rotate the knob to half way and measure from the wiper to each end. A 'linear' pot will read approximately the same on both halves, while a 'log' pot will read about 10 times higher on one side than the other. As usual it is best to do this with the pot disconnected from the circuit, to eliminate possible interference from other components.

[Potentiometer Tapers](http://www.resistorguide.com/potentiometer-taper/)

[image]

[image]